# Evaluating predicate logic formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

× denotes the multiplication operation.

$ (\forall x)(\forall z)(\exists y)(x × y = z) $

**Domain:** $\mathbb{Q}$

(Q.1) The answer I have says this formula would evaluate to **true** for this domain, which I don't understand.

If **x** was 0 ($\frac{0}{1}$) and **z** was 5 ($\frac{5}{1}$), then there exists no rational number **y**, such that 0 × y = 5

$\therefore$ $ (\forall x)(\forall z)(\exists y)(x × y = z) $ is **false** under this interpretation.

Am I correct or am I missing something here?

**Domain:** $\mathbb{R}$

(Q.2) Essentially my argument is the same for why this formula is false for this domain, but for brevity:

If **x** was 0.0 and **z** was 5.0, then there exists no real number **y**, such that 0.0 × y = 5.0

$\therefore$ $ (\forall x)(\forall z)(\exists y)(x × y = z) $ is **false**, under this interpretation.

Am I correct or am I missing something here?

Comment: Your arguments are correct, but could it be that a typo is to blame? $(\forall x )(\forall y )(\exists z)(x\times y = z)$ seems a lot more reasonable to me. Make sure you've read the question correctly, and if you did, I'd assume the expression above is what was really meant here.

Comment: @ChubbyChef Great observation. The previous question to this one was exactly that, so I'm pretty sure the change was intentional.

Comment: You’re answer is correct. Pretty sure it was a typo or some other mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the users in the comment section, I can conclude the arguments made are correct.

The formula was changed to:

$ (\forall x) (\forall z) (x \ne 0 \rightarrow (\exists y)(x \times y = z))$